# Nginx error recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while proxying connection

Tags: nginx

I am using Nginx for HTTP & TCP load balancing. HTTP is working fine, But i am getting below error for TCP load balancing. I am using Nginx ngx_stream_core_module module.

nginx version: nginx/1.9.13

Nginx error Logs :

```
2016/07/12 07:46:16 [error] 16737#16737: *32006 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while proxying connection, client: 27.50.X.X, server: 0.0.0.0:3030, upstream: "10.7.0.12:3030", bytes from/to client:354/318, bytes from/to upstream:318/354
2016/07/12 07:48:53 [error] 16737#16737: *32048 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while proxying connection, client: 27.50.X.X, server: 0.0.0.0:3030, upstream: "10.7.0.12:3030", bytes from/to client:324/292, bytes from/to upstream:292/324
2016/07/12 07:51:40 [error] 16737#16737: *32109 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while proxying connection, client: 27.50.X.X, server: 0.0.0.0:3030, upstream: "10.7.0.12:3030", bytes from/to client:324/292, bytes from/to upstream:292/324
```

Can anyone help me to understand why I am getting this errors ?

Is there any way to enable access logs for tcp requests coming to Nginx?

Comment: Did you find any solution for it? We are facing a similar issue.. Only few users are not able to connect, others are fine

Comment: @user18853 Debugging using tcpdump and wireshark helped me to find root cause. Client application was sending RST that's why it was getting disconnected.

Comment: Also found the problem not in nginx with the help of tcpdump and wireshark, Thanks.

Comment: Then, how the issue was fixed after coming to know the client is sending RST.